# How can I create an XBRL report which will show me error message that contains "enum2ie:InvalidEnumerationValue"?

Tags: enums, report, instance, enumerator, xbrl

I've created an XBRL report where I chose in the enumerator2 one element "K000Member". What should I change (spoil) so the program will notify me with message that contains this "enum2ie:InvalidEnumerationValue"?
[screenshot of the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvhzU.png)

So far I changed URI of an element and made it incorrect. But I'm not getting an error message that contains
"enum2ie:InvalidEnumerationValue".

The program notifies me with the error message that contains "enum2ie:InvalidEnumeration**Set**Value".

[screenshot of the report that I changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPEOv.png)